# Directory structure for web user profiles

Tags: linux

I'm doing a rewrite of a web app that allows users to set up profiles and upload pictures. The original version of the app set up the physical dirs on the filesystem (debian box, ext3 fs) like: /var/www/profiles/username

This app only has a few hundred users at the moment, but I'd like to do some futureproofing and make the structure a little more robust and limit each subdir to say 1000 or so dirs. I'd like to keep the users unique id (db int) out of the structure, but am not 100% opposed (I'd rather to have less critical info exposed about each user).

My initial thought was something like /var/www/profiles/year/month/day/hour/username, with the year, month, etc being the date the account was created. I'm just not sure this is the best approach.

I'd love to hear some ideas! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is realized on many bigger machines with multiple users.
A typical way to go about it would be:

```
/var/www/profiles/u/us/username
/var/www/profiles/p/pe/peter
```

etc.